# How to pass list items from controller to view

Tags: view, model, controller

I have a partialview and an action method in controller. In the action method I have different lists which I am binding to view, for my first div I am getting only single value but in my second list I may get multiple values which I need to pass them to view. When I am trying to passing them to view I am getting error. How can I pass list data from controller to view in mvc?

I was trying in this way by using for each loop but its not working

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
                @if ((item.Name1 != null))
                {
                    <p> @item .Name1 </p>
                }
                else
                {
                    <p> Not Available</p>
                }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult ViewInfo(long Id = 0)
        {
            UviewAhsPhMemberInfoProxyStub model = new UviewAhsPhMemberInfoProxyStub();
            try
            {

                esParameters parameters = new esParameters();
                parameters.Add("Id", Id);
                List<UviewBasicdataProxyStub> lstbasicdata = _resource.Activity.GetPhMemberInfo(parameters, timeDictionary).Result;
                List<UviewAdditionaldataProxyStub> lstadditionaldata = _resource.Activity.GetPhContactInfo(param).Result;
                if (lstbasicdata.Count > 0)
                {
                    var basicdata= lstbasicdata[0];
                    model.Name1 = basicdata.Name1.SetStringOrNotAvailable("Not Available");
                    model.Name2 = basicdata.Name2.SetStringOrNotAvailable("Not Available");
                    model.Name3 = basicdata.Name3.SetStringOrNotAvailable("Not Available");
                    model.Name4 = basicdata.Name4.SetStringOrNotAvailable("Not Available");           
                }

                if (lstadditionaldata.Count > 0)
                {
                    var additionaldata = lstadditionaldata[0];
                    model.Number1 = ConactInfo.Number1.SetStringOrNotAvailable("Not Available");
                    model.Number2 = ConactInfo.Number2.SetStringOrNotAvailable("Not Available");
                    model.Number3 = ConactInfo.Number3;
                    model.Number4 = ConactInfo.Number4.SetStringOrNotAvailable("Not Available"); //county
                    model.Number5 = ConactInfo.Number5.SetStringOrNotAvailable("Not Available");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.Message.ToString();
            }
            return PartialView(model);
        }
```

View-

```
//first div
<div class="row" style="max-height:450px;overflow-y:auto;width:100%"> 
<div class="column">
                <p style="font-weight: 700;"> Name1 </p>
                @if ((Model.Name1 != null))
                {
                    <p> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name1) </p>
                }
                else
                {
                    <p> Not Available</p>
                }
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <p style="font-weight: 700;"> Name2 </p>
                @if ((Model.Name2 != null))
                {
                    <p>  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name2) </p>
                }
                else
                {
                    <p> Not Available</p>
                }
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <p style="font-weight: 700;"> Name3 </p>
                @if ((Model.Name3 != null))
                {
                    <p>  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name3) </p>
                }
                else
                {
                    <p> Not Available</p>
                }
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <p style="font-weight: 700;"> Name4 </p>
                @if ((Model.Name4 != null))
                {
                    <p>  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name4) </p>
                }
                else
                {
                    <p> Not Available</p>
                }
            </div>
</div>
//second div
<div class="row" style="max-height:450px;overflow-y:auto;width:100%"> 
<div class="column">
                <p style="font-weight: 700;"> Number1 </p>
                @if ((Model.Number1 != null))
                {
                    <p> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Number1) </p>
                }
                else
                {
                    <p> Not Available</p>
                }
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <p style="font-weight: 700;"> Number2 </p>
                @if ((Model.Number2 != null))
                {
                    <p>  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Number2) </p>
                }
                else
                {
                    <p> Not Available</p>
                }
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <p style="font-weight: 700;"> Number3 </p>
                @if ((Model.Number3 != null))
                {
                    <p>  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Number3) </p>
                }
                else
                {
                    <p> Not Available</p>
                }
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <p style="font-weight: 700;"> Number4 </p>
                @if ((Model.Number4 != null))
                {
                    <p>  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Number4) </p>
                }
                else
                {
                    <p> Not Available</p>
                }
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <p style="font-weight: 700;"> Number5 </p>
                @if ((Model.Number5 != null))
                {
                    <p>  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Number5) </p>
                }
                else
                {
                    <p> Not Available</p>
                }
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i am not getting how to add more over one more mistake that i am doing is if my list item count is 3 i am pulling on list item at zero index hence i am able to view only list items which are at zero index var additionaldata = lstadditionaldata[0]; at this line

Comment: can anybody help me out